# Should i upgrade my Microphone or my Interface first?

Tags: microphone, recording, audio-interfaces, hardware

Good Day,

Im searching for my next upgrade in Hardware.
At the moment i am working with:

Steinberg UR MKII (Audio Interface)
Rode NT1A (Microphone)
KRK RP5 G4 (Monitors)

My Room is sound-treated. As i have read "mixing secrets for the small studio".

I have heard magic about the UAudio Apollo (Twin / Solo)

Im producing mainly HipHop/RnB/Rock for Microphones in the next price class i would think of the Neumann T87/TLM102 or the Sennheiser MK4 which i have taken out of most of my recherches.

So im asking people with experience and maybe the knowledge of a small homestudio which upgrades slowly every 2-3 months.

The Budget is about 500€-2500€ (obviously every i would consider other Answers for the Upgrade after this one)

I simply dont know where to upgrade, will the AudioInterface improve the Workflow as i heard so notably big that its worth to upgrade it before the microphone? Or will Buying a more Powerfull Microphone overload the Interface?

Im very interested in the Answers, i have been active in StackOverflow ever since and realy looking forward to being active here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apollo with  a neumann 102 would be my choice  setup - based on what you have said... the UA system is great for writers like yourself.....I would probably try to buy both on the used market and use leftover cash for a few UA plugins.